# EventListener is returning to a thread that didn't call it. This is creating a deadlock when it calls methods in the main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, listener, deadlock

I am logging and fairly new to threads. My main thread is 1, a listener is started in another thread and on return calls to my main methods come from another thread.

This is creating a deadlock on yet another thread which is in a 3rd party package.

Is my understanding right? Or is thread 1 scrapped for a new one?

Comment: Threads are hard enough to debug when you have the code.  But I would say impossible without it.  So please post an [mre] that demonstrates the problem you are having.  That also means provide some POJ code that emulates the 3rd party package in POJ.  Otherwise, folks won't be able to help you as much.

Comment: do not make blocking calls from callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexei Kaigorodov said:

"do not make blocking calls from callbacks"